# putty connect successfully, while pscp run into "server refused our key"

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I create one SUSE linux EC2 instance in Amazon AWS.

And it is OK to 'putty' to access the instance (use the key-pair file, let's call it key.pem, I have converted it to key.ppk), and when log in the host, I am using 'root' user name, and it is OK.

```
login as: root
Authenticating with public key "imported-openssh-key"
Last login: Tue Apr 15 15:17:55 2014 from x.x.x.x
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP3 x86_64 (64-bit)

As "root" use the:
  - zypper command for package management
  - yast command for configuration management

Management and Config: https://www.suse.com/suse-in-the-cloud-basics
Documentation: http://www.suse.com/documentation/sles11/

Have a lot of fun...
```

While when I try to use 'pscp' to copy files, it always failed, and outputs

```
Server refused our key
Using Keyboard-interactive authentication.
Password:
```

My 'pscp' command usage as following

```
C:\Users\t440s\Downloads\putty\pscp.exe -i key.pps test.txt root@myhost.compute.amazonaws.com:/tmp
```

Actually, I do not know my password.

And I checked following section of /etc/ssh/sshd_config, seems root do not need password

```
# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin without-password

PasswordAuthentication no
```

I am using win8.

Please help me. Yours.

Comment: Your command line shows key.pps, is that correct?

Comment: sorry，it is a typo, should be ppk

Comment: Could you please provide any resolution? Thanks

Comment: For anyone else who runs into "Server refused our key", in my case it was because the username was wrong. PuTTY prompts for a username, but pscp does not, hence my confusion as to why PuTTY worked but pscp did not. (And on windows subsystem for linux (WSL), I have the same username as the server, but on normal windows, I do not)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like you should use Git Bash tool http://git-scm.com/download/win its free and opensource, Please download and install , You have Unix environment is windows :) 
now in the git bash type command **ls** to check where you are and now you can type this command in GIT bash

```
scp -i /c/Users/USERNAME/Download/key.pem filename.txt ec2-user@ec2-81.1821.1..eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:/tmp
```

You can replace the user ec2-user to ubuntu or any other which is associate to that machine I dont think root work. Let me know is that works for you

Comment: Why would Git Bash handle that ssh command line any different from any other shell?  The important thing is getting a command-line version of ssh and scp for this test.

Comment: You are also right but its easy to use if you are copy a file in linux ec2 node and Git Bash provide you the facility. I have try it and feel like linux shell on windows